# Search and replace in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to search a sentence and replace it with the value of hash that matched string like this:

```
my $sentence = "abc def hello hi";
$sentence =~ s/abc def/$hash{'abc def'}/g;
```

I am not getting the correct output.
Can any one please help me?

Comment: What is the correct output? what is the content of `$hash{'abc def'}`?

Comment: the value of $hash{'abc def'} hello hi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = ( 'abc def' => 'pqr xyz' );

my $sentence = "abc def hello hi";
$sentence =~ s/abc def/$hash{'abc def'}/g;

print "$sentence\n";
```

When run, it prints:

```
pqr xyz hello hi
```

If that's not what you expected, what were you expecting?  (Note that there were a number of typos in the original version of the Perl code in the question; I assumed they were incidental, but maybe they were key to your problem.  Using `use strict;` and `use warnings;` helps spot problems such as misspelled variable names.)